# Connection reset by peer by oracle on processing of java application

Tags: java, sql, oracle10g

I am trying to insert the tens of millions of data into oracle database by through java application but after 850k data inserted I am getting the error:

> java.sql.exception: IO Exception :Connection reset by peer socket
>   write error.

Comment: It means that you had already been closed connection before you try flush or close connection.

Comment: NO, I opened only one  connection , i close the connection until unless the process completed.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar issue in my aplication.

In my case, after a few minutes in which the connection has not used, oracle server resets the connection and when I had to use it again, this exception was thrown.

I found that the problem was that oracle sets the timeout for connection at 10 minutes in sqlora.net file.

Maybe you can try to increase this time interval or check if the connection is still valid instead to check if it is closed (a connection can be not valid even if it is not closed).

The last option works fine for me.

I hope this helps.

Comment: which property was setting connection timeout to 10mins